# How to retrieve data from a device from an android application

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm currently trying to connect to a device (mainly it is a PCA plus a bluetooth device via rs-232). The problem I have is that I have connected and paired both devices (the PCA and the App) but I have no idea how to retrieve the data from the PCA.

I have a code that mainly I've taken from android documentation/tutorial (https://github.com/mitchtabian/Sending-and-Receiving-Data-with-Bluetooth) this code, can send and receive data from a device to another (phone to phone for example but any bluetooth should work).

The PCA (build with atm2560), is like a blackbox to me I have no idea how to access the data also I have not clear if just the device by itself can provide me the data via bluetooth that i ask for and get it in my phone.

Could you please provide me at least some guidelines of what I could do to progress? I mean, I guess is not hard when you know how to but to be honest I may be wrong but I'm really stuck.

Cheers,

Comment: What is a PCA??

Comment: first what do you mean with PCA in electronics and devices that means many things and nowadays almost every device comes with bluetooth connectivity.
but regardless what PCA meaning, if you want to communicate 2 devices they need to use the same communication protocol, bluetooth is like the pipeline between the devices but also you need the communication protocol for example if they send each other Morse Code Messages. usually bluetooth uses L2CAP protocol, and you can emulate RS232 but you just emulate the baudios in RX and TX the serial signal could be Morse or other binary signal.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, you'll need to know what protocol does your PCA use (I don't even know what a PCA is).

Android SDK supports the following protocols:

- RFCOMM (any data)
- A2DP (audio only)
- HDP (audio only)
- GATT (bluetooth low energy)

If your PCA doesn't support neither RFCOMM nor GATT (for example, it uses a custom protocol). There's not much you can do. The only limit is what does Android SDK offer.

If your PCA uses RFCOMM or GATT, you can log everything it receives from the device (you mentioned it's a blackbox to you).